# How to check comobo box empty or not

Tags: javafx

I'm crating a from using JavaFx, so i use some combo box and datepikers. now i wanna know how to check those are empty or not for validation purposes.

i tried already like this,

```
public void btnIssueOnAction(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    if(dtpDate.getValue()){
        new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR,"Date filed is empty",ButtonType.OK).show();
        return;
    }else if(cmbCustomerID.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().equals(null)){
        new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR,"Please select customer Id",ButtonType.OK).show();
        return;
    }else if(cmbVehicleID.getSelectionModel().equals(null)){
        new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR,"Please select vehicle Id",ButtonType.OK).show();
        return;
    }else if(cmbDriverStatues.getSelectionModel().equals(null)){
        new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR,"Please select driver statues",ButtonType.OK).show();
        return;
    }else if(cmbDriverStatues.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().equals("With Driver")){
        if(cmbDriverID.getSelectionModel().equals(null)){
            new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR,"Please select driver id",ButtonType.OK).show();
            return;
```

Comment: what do you mean by _empty_? your snippet won't compile (assuming dtpDate is the DatePicker) Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem - mind the __M__!

Comment: find the answer for combo box issue , i wanna insert value from JFXDatePicker so i need to check whether this field empty or not .sorry for my English i hope you get my point .

Comment: A reference cannot automatically converted to `boolean`, unless its type is `Boolean`. `if (dtpDate.getValue())` would only work, if `dtpDate` is a `ComboBox<Boolean>`... As for `comboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().equals(null)` This never yields true. Either the item is indeed `null` and you get a NPE or the result is `false` for every properly implemented `equals` method. Just use `==` to compare to `null`: `(dtpDate.getValue() == null)`; `Objects.equals` could be used for stuff like `cmbDriverStatues.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().equals("With Driver")` Alt: yoda notation

Comment: Please be clear with your question

Comment: @MohinuddinLuhar sorry for that , my english skill is not good : (